# React submitting data with child component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state, onchange

I am currently working on React and I have question how I should organize the layout of the component for my project. So, basically I have a parent component and two child components. I was able to send the state to parent component and trying to submit the data(which was received from the child component) to the database. The button is located on the parent component. But whenever I submit the data it will send the previous data which I was submitted before. I will draw the logic that I did and post it below this question.

**Note**:
Send the function by props from parent to child and call the props on child after onchange is called on the select box or dropdown. The onchange will set the state first and call the props.

I am new to react so please tell me if there is better layout. I am willing to learn from my mistake.

[image]

(PARENT COMPONENT)

```
class Vten extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        cbValue: "",
        cValue: ""
      }
}

handleClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var passOne = this.state.cbValue;
    var passTwo = this.state.cValue;
    const data = {passOne,passTwo};
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }
    fetch('/api/vten',options);
}

handleInputValue = (val, val2) => {
     alert(val);
     alert(val2);
    this.setState({ 
        cbValue: val,
        cValue: val2
    });
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col><h3>V-10 - Vendor / Partner / Client Registration</h3></Col>
                </Row>

                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <VtenTwo handleInput={this.handleInputValue}/>
                    </Col>
                </Row>

                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                            Save for Later
                        </Button>
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                        <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                            Submit for Review
                        </Button>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default Vten;
```

(CHILD COMPONENT)

```
class VtenTwo extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        checkVendor: true,
        checkPartner: false,
        checkClient: false,
        checkBoxValue: "checkVendor",
        CountryDropdown: "USA"
      }
}

onCheckChange = (e) =>{
    if("checkVendor" === e.target.name){
        this.setState({
            checkVendor: true,
            checkPartner: false,
            checkClient: false,
            checkBoxValue: e.target.value
        })
    }else if("checkPartner" === e.target.name){
        this.setState({
            checkVendor: false,
            checkPartner: true,
            checkClient: false,
            checkBoxValue: e.target.value
        })
    }else{
        this.setState({
            checkVendor: false,
            checkPartner: false,
            checkClient: true,
            checkBoxValue: e.target.value
        })
    } 
    //this.props.handleInput(this.state.checkBoxValue);
    this.changedValue();
}

handleCountryChange = e => {
    this.setState({
        CountryDropdown: e.target.value
    })
    //this.props.handleInput2(this.state.CountryDropdown);
    this.changedValue();
}

//this is called from save button(child) and call function on parent
changedValue = () => {
    let ck = this.state.checkBoxValue;
    let dp = this.state.CountryDropdown;
    this.props.handleInput(ck,dp);
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
             <label>
               <b>Step 2. Enter Entity Information</b>
            </label> <br/>

            <label>General Information</label> <br/>
            <label><b>{this.state.checkBoxValue}</b></label><br/>
            <label><b>{this.state.CountryDropdown}</b></label><br/>
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <label>Select Account Type</label>
                        <div className="radio">
                            <Form.Check inline label="Vendor" type="checkbox" name="checkVendor" value="Vendor" checked={this.state.checkVendor} onChange={this.onCheckChange} />
                            <Form.Check inline label="Partner" type="checkbox" name="checkPartner" value= "Partner" checked={this.state.checkPartner} onChange={this.onCheckChange}/>
                            <Form.Check inline label="Client" type="checkbox" name="checkClient" value= "Client" checked={this.state.checkClient} onChange={this.onCheckChange}/>                   
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                        <label>Country</label>
                        <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect1">
                            <Form.Control as="select" value={this.state.CountryDropdown} onChange={this.handleCountryChange}>
                                {/* <option value="">None</option> */}
                                <option value="USA">USA</option>
                                <option value="KOREA">KOREA</option>
                                <option value="JAPAN">JAPAN</option>
                            </Form.Control>
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Col>
                    {/* <Col>
                        <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={this.changedValue}>
                            Save
                        </Button>
                    </Col> */}
                </Row>
            </Container>


        </div>
    );
}
 }

 export default VtenTwo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to here from React official doc:
https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up

Lifting up your child state up is one possible solution:
1. Define your state in the parent instead of in the child
2. Pass the state to your child as props.
3. Do set state in the parent, if your child needs to do set state, pass your set state function to your child in props too.
4. After set state, your parent will re-render, your child will also be re-rendered since props value change

What you mentioned sent previous data, it is most likely related to wrong state handling. Share your code here could better resolve your problem.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response to my question. As you said i will take a look at the link you sent me and i have also uploaded the code above. Thank You again

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the previous state because the setState is an asynchronous function and you are trying to fetch the state data before it is set to the state.

You can use callback inside setState to wait for the state to get updated before calling the other function will solve your problem.

```
    onCheckChange = (e) =>{
        if("checkVendor" === e.target.name){
            this.setState({
                checkVendor: true,
                checkPartner: false,
                checkClient: false,
                checkBoxValue: e.target.value
            }, () => {
                 this.changedValue();
            })
        }else if("checkPartner" === e.target.name){
            this.setState({
                checkVendor: false,
                checkPartner: true,
                checkClient: false,
                checkBoxValue: e.target.value
            }, () => {
                this.changedValue();
            })
        }else{
            this.setState({
                checkVendor: false,
                checkPartner: false,
                checkClient: true,
                checkBoxValue: e.target.value
            }, () => {
               this.changedValue();
            })
        }

    }

    handleCountryChange = e => {
        this.setState({
            CountryDropdown: e.target.value
        }, () => {
           this.changedValue();
        });

    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have been stuck for days trying to figure it out. I have learned from you and again thank you.